# How to covert simple (flat) array to multi-dimensional (2D) arrays

Tags: arrays, perl, multidimensional-array

I have following code in the Perl language:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my $DF = "/usr/bin/df -Pk"; # HP-UX
my @temp = split /\n/, `$DF`;
shift @temp;
print Dumper \@temp;
```

And the output is something as below (shorter for better readability):

```
$VAR1 = [
          '/dev/vg00/lvol6       114224    46304    67920    41%     /home',
          '/dev/vg00/lvol7       8340704  4336752  4003952   52%     /opt',
          '/dev/vg00/lvol4       520952    35080   485872     7%     /tmp',
        ];
```

I want to converting the `@temp` array (or create a new array) to multi-dimensional (array of arrays) like this:

```
$VAR1 = [
          ['/dev/vg00/lvol6', 114224, 46304, 67920, '41%', '/home'],
          ['/dev/vg00/lvol7', 8340704, 4336752, 4003952, '52%', '/opt'],
          ['/dev/vg00/lvol4', 520952, 35080, 485872, '7%', '/tmp'],
        ];
```

Anyone help? Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: You can skip the split on newline if you use an array for the backtick capture: `my @DF = \`/usr/bin/df -Pk`

Comment: Also for an alternative to using backticks: http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=177225

Comment: @TLP: Thanks for info! But to avoid something like this `Can't locate Filesys/DiskSpace.pm in @INC` and the `Filesys::Df` module needs to be compiled I rely on the system `df` command.

Comment: As far as I know, the cpan tool takes care of compilation and installation of a module. Did you use the cpan tool?

Comment: @TLP: Yes, but I do not have access to the HP-UX compiler. :-/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
@temp = map [ split ], @temp ;
```

Comment: Working in @TLP's suggestion: `@temp = map [ split ], \`$DF\``

Comment: Thanks for this, I didn't realise aliasing happened if you just used a simple expression but map would be kind of pointless in that case if it didn't :D

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would do it

```
my @lines = `$DF`;
my @data  = map { [split] } @lines;
print Dumper \@data;
```

This is assuming that there is no unexpected whitespace in a path